# How to set eWay value attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<script src="https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.js"
   class="eway-paynow-button"
   data-publicapikey=""
   data-amount="1000"
   data-currency="AUD" >
</script>
```

How can I set data-amount from a Javascript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on nikhil's solution, you can change the text like so:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("eway-paynow-button")[0].setAttribute("data-amount", "2000");
document.getElementsByClassName("eway-button")[0].firstElementChild.innerHTML = "Pay Now ($20.00)";
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was after!

Answer (score 1):

you can try following

(assuming you have the class `eway-paynow-button` only to the script element)

```
document.getElementsByClassName("eway-paynow-button")[0].dataset.amount = 1000;
```

Or a more generic solution

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("eway-paynow-button");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
   if(elems[i].getAttribute('src') === "https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.js") {
      elems[i].dataset.amount = 1000;
   }
}
```

Comment: That does work, I have noticed that the button text doesn't change. Though the correct value appears in the iframe when you click the pay now button, Is there anyway to "refresh" the button text?

Comment: @Ricadam - Please add more details as the above does not gives the complete picture of the scenario

Comment: Please refer to this codepen http://codepen.io/richeydesign/pen/WryjPz?editors=0010 
What I'm trying to do is change the text after calculating the value first. the original text (0.00) does not change when the value of the amount changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use my jQuery Solution to change your button text problem

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>X</title>
</head>
 <body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.js"
   class="eway-paynow-button"
   data-publicapikey=""
   data-amount="1000"
   data-currency="AUD" >
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // jQuery Document
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".eway-paynow-button").attr("data-amount",2000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please refer to this codepen codepen.io/richeydesign/pen/WryjPz?editors=0010 What I'm trying to do is change the text after calculating the value first. the original text (0.00) does not change when the value of the amount changes.